# Standalone spring (no boot) library

Tags: java, spring, jar

I was wondering: is it possible to create a spring (not boot) library so that its context is invisible to the caller?

I have a spring mvc app A. After some refactoring I gathered some functionality in a library L so that I can use it in A and in another other project P.
Right now, to make it work, I am forced to import L's context inside P but I don't like this solution at all.

I would like my library to be a black box that i can plug in where I need without having to merge the caller's context with the library one.

For example, L works on a database so it's going to need a dataSource. Let's call Foo the class in L which I would call from P.
In P I have my dataSource so the perfect solution would be to use the Foo class by defining in P just the bean

```
<bean id="foo" class="L.Foo">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and leaving all the beans needed by Foo (for example the EntityManager) hidden inside L. Unaccessible from the outside.

Is there some way to achieve something like this?

If not, or if my idea is flawed, do you have some other suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: It seems you could really benefit from spring boot autoconfigurations. I don't know if you could can achieve exactly what you ask with vanilla spring.